# AngularJS: None scope functions in a directive seem not to be isolated

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I have a problem with multiple instances of the same directive on the same page like in the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjbmj7cm/6/) example. Each directive has his own sort button and draws a small bar chart with d3. And this button should sort the corresponding directive. I would like to use the directive to show multiple barcharts on the same page, with different data sets.

The problem is that the sort button always sorts the last directive (no matter how many are there) and uses the data of his scope. All other charts stay the same. The scope seems to be isolated for the data but not for the function. I think I missed something with the scopes but I have no idea why the behaviour is like this. Any hints?

This is what the return of the directive looks like:

```
return {
            restrict : "E",
            transclude: true,
            scope : {
                "data" : "="
            },
            template : "<div><button ng-click='func()'>Sort</button></div>",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs)
            {
                init(element, scope);

              scope.func = function()
              {
                scope.data = scope.data.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
                render(scope);
              }
            }
        }
```

The controller provides the data. The function `func()` sorts the data. I think the problem is around the `render()` function which is defined in the directive and not in the `link:` expression. But I am not sure.

Comment: Can you post the render function?  Maybe recreate this in jsfiddle/plunkr/codepen?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but easiest fix is to assign your `svg` variable back to your scope:  http://jsfiddle.net/cjbmj7cm/7/

Comment: @jusopi The Jsfiddle link is in the first sentence :)

Comment: @Mark Thanks thats an easy fix!

Comment: The problem is that i have to add all variables (a lot...)explicitly to the scope. I hope there is a way to make the whole directive somehow isolated.

Comment: Oops, sorry completely missed it.  That's what I get for reading these on my phone.